# how to hide things after certain time in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am creating a video player in android studio. I want to hide buttons, layout and media controller after 5 seconds and I am using gestures for different properties but the issue is that when I apply 2 to 3  gestures in a certain time, after 5 seconds the buttons and media controller start blinking. I use this code for stying on screen

```
centerlayout.setOnTouchListener(new LinearLayout.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                if (gestureDetectorc.onTouchEvent(m)) {
                    if(m.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                hide();
                            }
                        },5000);


                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide the snippet of `hide` method

Comment: In hide function I am using mediacontroller. hide(), backbtn. hide(), forwardbtn. hide(), and toplayout. hide()

Comment: Your code is correct here. Do you mean  `mediacontroller.hide()` is `mediacontroller.setVisiblity(View.GONE)`?

Comment: Yes I use it but problem is with post delay handler because when I use 2 to 3 time handler they hide after every 5 seconds such as if I use gesture first time and then, I use gesture again in 4 second then after 1 second it will get hide due to which it start blinking when I use gesture many time

Comment: Good, then save the runnable and do post delay after removing the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the runnable in global

```
Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                hide();
                            }
                        };
```

call `removeCallbacks` before you call `postDelay`

```
centerlayout.setOnTouchListener(new LinearLayout.OnTouchListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent m) {
                if (gestureDetectorc.onTouchEvent(m)) {
                    if(m.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        handler.removeCallbacks(mRunnable);//add this
                        handler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 5000);
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks you solved my problem and also giving me your time.